# Pytorch model performing worse than tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch

I have the following tensorflow model, that tries to predict a time series, based on lagging values.

I then tried to translate it to pytorch and it works fine but performs significantly worse. Is there any obvious difference between the two models that could contribute to pytorch performing worse? Any suggestions are greatly apprecaited.

## tensorflow model:

early_stop = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss',
min_delta=1e-3,
patience=3,
verbose=2, mode='auto')
tbCallBack = PlotLossesKeras()

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(50, input_shape=(look_back, 1)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
model.fit(train_x, train_y,
          epochs=2000,
          batch_size=20, verbose=1)
```

## Pytorch Model:

```
class LSTMForecaster(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size, num_layers, output_size):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(input_size, hidden_size, num_layers)
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(0.2)
        self.linear = nn.Linear(hidden_size, output_size)
        
    def forward(self, input_seq):
        lstm_out, _ = self.lstm(input_seq)
        dropout = self.dropout(lstm_out)
        predictions = self.linear(dropout)
        return predictions
        
loss_fn = nn.MSELoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model_1.parameters())
model_1 = LSTMForecaster(input_size=3, hidden_size=50, num_layers=1, output_size=1)

torch.manual_seed(45)
epochs = 2000 
batch_size = 20
num_batches = len(train_x) // batch_size
train_x = train_x.to(device)
test_x = test_x.to(device)
train_y = train_y.to(device)
test_y = test_y.to(device)

for epoch in range(epochs):
    for i in range(num_batches):
        # Get the current batch of data
        start = i * batch_size
        end = start + batch_size
        x_batch = train_x[start:end]
        y_batch = train_y[start:end]

        pred_y = model_1(x_batch)
        loss = loss_fn(pred_y, y_batch)
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
            

    model_1.eval()
```

Comment: you've defined your optimizer before your model, is your model actually optimizing?

Comment: @jhso The way it is the code wouldn't even run as model_1 is not defined when the optimizer is created...